# Text of a cell is highlighted after starting editing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, edit

I load the contents of a database (mdb) into a `DataTable` object and display them in a `DataGrid` so that I can edit them. As soon as I start editing a cell (pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>), the entire text is selected.

[image: Left (actual): All text is selected on edit. Right (expected): Caret is moved to end on edit.]

Is there a way to prevent this marking?

My `DataGrid` markup:

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" Height="750" Width="1920" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowHeight="25" FrozenColumnCount="1" x:Name="DataGrid1" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="13" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,120" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" SelectionMode="Extended">

   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Width="450" Header=" Column1 " Binding="{Binding Column1}">
           <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
               <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                   <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="150"></Setter>
               </Style>
           </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
       </DataGridTextColumn>
   
       <DataGridTextColumn Width="120" Header=" Column2 " Binding="{Binding Column2}">
           <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
               <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                   <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="10"></Setter>
               </Style>
           </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
       </DataGridTextColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
   
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
           <EventSetter Event="KeyDown"  Handler="DATAGRID_Keydown" ></EventSetter>
       </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>

</DataGrid>
```

My C# Code:

```
private void DATAGRID_Keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab | e.Key == Key.F2)
    {
      DataGrid1.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `PreparingCellForEdit` event for the `DataGrid`:

XAML

```
<DataGrid ... PreparingCellForEdit="DataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit">
```

C# (It will place the cursor at the end of the current cell text)

```
private void DataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)e.EditingElement).SelectionStart = ((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text.Length;
}
```

You can use use `((TextBox)e.EditingElement).SelectionStart = 0;` to place the cursor at the beginning of the original text of that cell.

Comment: Very simple and working solution. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to adding a handler for `PreparingCellEdit` in code-behind, you could create a behavior that encapsulates the code for moving the caret of the `TextBox` in order to make it reusable across multiple views without copy-pasting the code for each instance.

You have to install the [*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf) NuGet package and create a behavior for `DataGrid`. The behavior adds a handler to `PreparingCellEdit` and sets the caret to the end. There is also an attached property which enables you to exclude columns from the behavior. By inverting the default value, you could disable the behavior by default and enable it explicitly for each column.

```
public class PrepareTextEditBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty MoveCaretToEndProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "MoveCaretToEnd", typeof(bool), typeof(PrepareTextEditBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(true));

   public static bool GetMoveCaretToEnd(DependencyObject obj)
   {
      return (bool)obj.GetValue(MoveCaretToEndProperty);
   }

   public static void SetMoveCaretToEnd(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
   {
      obj.SetValue(MoveCaretToEndProperty, value);
   }

   protected override void OnAttached()
   {
      base.OnAttached();
      AssociatedObject.PreparingCellForEdit += OnPreparingCellForEdit;
   }

   protected override void OnDetaching()
   {
      base.OnDetaching();
      AssociatedObject.PreparingCellForEdit -= OnPreparingCellForEdit;
   }

   private static void OnPreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
   {
      if (!GetMoveCaretToEnd(e.Column))
         return;

      var textBox = (TextBox)e.EditingElement;
      textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
   }
}
```

To use the behavior, simply add it to the data grid in the `Interaction.Behaviors` tag.

```xml
<DataGrid ...>
   <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <local:PrepareTextEditBehavior/>
   </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <DataGrid.Columns>

      <DataGridTextColumn ...>
         <!-- ...column markup. -->
         <!-- ...the behavior is applied here by default. -->
      </DataGridTextColumn>

      <DataGridTextColumn ...
                          local:PrepareTextEditBehavior.MoveCaretToEnd="False">
         <!-- ...column markup. -->
         <!-- ...the behavior is NOT applied here explicitly. -->
      </DataGridTextColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```